# how to make apple iap server notification endpoint security

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

Now I am define a endpoint to receive apple server notification in spring boot project:

```
@Api
@RequestMapping("/post/notification")
@FeignClient(name = "dolphin-post-service")
@Validated
public interface IAppleServerNotificationController {

    /**
     * Receive Apple Server Notification
     * @param
     * @return
     */
    @PostMapping("/v1/appleSeverNotification")
    Response<Integer> handleNotification(@RequestBody ServerNotificationRequest request);
}
```

the request:

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class ServerNotificationRequest implements Serializable {

    @ApiModelProperty(value = "responseBody")
    private String responseBody;

}
```

but the api on my server side have auth to invoke, now I am facing the problem: if I have auth with my api, the apple server could not invoke because the apple server did not implemeent the auth 2.0 to get accessToken from my server. If I remove auth with the endpoint, that means anyone could invoke the endpoint if he known the address.

so what should I do to make the endpoint secure and allow apple to invoke? should I keep the endpoint not public? but some tools would sniff the url I think. what should I do?

Comment: You validate the supplied receipt with Apple. Only Apple can supply valid receipts. Anyone else who invokes the endpoint cannot supply a valid receipt

Comment: Ok, Thank you. I kown what should I do.@Paulw11

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now I am verify the shared scret in the server side like this:

```
    @Override
    @NoCheck
    public Response handleNotification(ServerNotificationRequest request) {
        if (!SHARED_SECRET.equals(request.getSharedSecret())) {
            log.error("illegal invoke：" + JSON.toJSONString(request));
            return new Response();
        }
        saveNotification(request);
        return new Response<>();
    }
```